# Center an element

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I center a `div` that is holding other elements. As default it seems that the `div` has the width of its parent tag, in this case `body`. What I want to do is center the `div`, do I need to set the width of it myself pixel by pixel? or is there an easier way of doing this.

Image of what Im talking about [image]

In the picture you can see Ive set the width of `div #container` to `250px` to center it with `margin: 0 auto;` but now its bigger than `table` which means the children of `#container` isn't in the exact center.

Comment: Give the div `display: inline-block`

Comment: That gave it the right width, but now margin:0 auto; isnt working :(

Comment: There is no perfect way to do it with css, you need to use javascript.

Comment: Give its container `text-align: center;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO 1](http://jsbin.com/EdEfuSe/1/edit)**

```
<div id="container">

</div>
```

```
#container{
  display:table;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

---

**[DEMO 2](http://jsbin.com/EdEfuSe/2/edit)**

```
<div id="container"> 
 <span id="form">

 </span>
</div>
```

```
#container{
   text-align:center;
}
#form{
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How bout setting  top and left 50%, fixing the position and margins=size of your div?

```
div {
      position: fixed;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      margin-top: -your size;
      margin-left: -your size;
    }
```

Comment: This is what I didn't want to do, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You could try percentages rather than px

```
<style>
    #container{
        width:30%;
        /* width:250px; will still be ok */
    }
    #container table{
        width:100%;
        /* This will make the table stretch or squash to fill the container */
        /* You could also try */
        margin: 0 auto;
        /* This will center the table inside the div*/
    }
<style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the parent div to `text-align: center;` and the div containing the content to `display: inline-block;`

In your case:

```
body {
text-align: center;
}

#container {
display: inline-block;
}
```